# How to set jest test for testing rest api

Tags: node.js, api, jestjs, supertest

I'm start learning jest testing and have a problem.
This is my code for testing:

```js
const getTask = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id: taskId } = req.params;
    const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: taskId });
    if (!task) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: `No task with id: ${taskId}` });
    }
    res.status(200).json({ task });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: error });
  }
};
```

This is the test:

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn('../controllers/tasks.js', 'getTask')

await supertest(app)
  .get(`/api/V1/tasks/61cadf4faf43ccd9f0d9d652`)
  .expect(404)
```

And I have this result:

```
Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; string given

  21 |       it('should return 404', async () => {
  22 |         const spy = jest.spyOn('../controllers/tasks.js', 'getTask')
> 23 |
     | ^
  24 |         await supertest(app)
  25 |           .get(`/api/V1/tasks/61cadf4faf43ccd9f0d9d652`)
  26 |           .expect(404)

  at ModuleMocker.spyOn (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:785:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__test__/task.test.js:23:12)
```

Comment: Just like the error says, [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) needs to be called with an _object,_ not a string (or in this case, the location of a file). I think you are thinking of [`jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), which does take module names.

Comment: What's the point of that test, even? You're integration testing the transport layer but mocking out the _controller_?